# Select all input tags where type is not checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, input, css-selectors

I need CSS selector that match all input tags where type is **not** `checkbox`.

This match:

`<input value="Meow!" />`

`<input type="password" />`

...but this does **not**:

`<input type="checkbox" />`

Because type is `checkbox`!

This is what I have at the moment:

`input:not(type="checkbox")`

Unfortunately, it does **not** work!

So here comes my questions:

1. How to fix my CSS3 selector?
2. Is it possible without CSS3 and JavaScript?
3. Is it possible without CSS3, but with use of JavaScript?

Thanks in any advice!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. Your attribute selector is missing the square brackets:

   ```
   input:not([type="checkbox"])
   ```
2. If you're applying styles you will need to make use of an override rule in CSS:

   ```
   input {
       /* Styles for all inputs */
   }

   input[type="checkbox"] {
       /* Override and revert above styles for checkbox inputs */
   }
   ```

   As you can imagine, it's almost impossible to do this for form elements because their browser-default styles aren't well-defined in CSS.
3. jQuery provides a [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector) that you can use:

   ```
   $('input:not(:checkbox)')
   ```

   You can also use the same selector as you do in CSS:

   ```
   $('input:not([type="checkbox"])')
   ```

Comment: Thanks! The one idea I got — I could define all possible input types except `checkbox` and apply my custom CSS to them. Then, only, `input` tag without type specified would fail.

Comment: @daGrevis: Yes, that's a good alternative. You should be avoiding `input` elements without types anyway.

Comment: Why's that? It's HTML5 valid and easier to type.

Comment: If you make it a point to specify the type, you can use attribute selectors without worrying about inputs without types :)

Answer (score 5):

`input:not([type="checkbox"])`

Comment: Should refresh the page more frequently... :)